# An not handle exception: Read rights conflict, Pointer value out of limit

Tags: c++

[image]

```
void TableInsert(SLinkListType &L, RedType d[], int n)
/* 由数组D建立n个元素的表插入排序的静态链表L */
{
    int i, p, q;
    L.r[0].rc.key = INT_MAX;
    L.r[0].next = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        L.r[i + 1].rc = d[i];
        q = 0;
        p = L.r[0].next;
        while (L.r[p].rc.key <= L.r[i + 1].rc.key)
        {
            q = p;
            p = L.r[p].next;
        }
        L.r[i + 1].next = p;
        L.r[q].next = i + 1;
    }
    L.length = n;
}//TableInsert

void Arrange(SLinkListType &L)
{
    int i, p, q;
    SLNode t;
    p = L.r[0].next;
    for (i = 1; i < L.length; i++)
    {
        while (p < i)
            p = L.r[p].next;
        q = L.r[p].next;
        if (p != i)
        {
            t = L.r[p];             /* 交换记录，使第i个记录到位 */
            L.r[p] = L.r[i];
            L.r[i] = t;
            L.r[i].next = p;
        }
        p = q;                      /* p指示尚未调整的表尾，为找第i+1个记录作准备 */
    }
}//Arrange

void Sort(SLinkListType L, int adr[])
/* 求得adr[1..L.length]，adr[i]为静态链表L的第i个最小记录的序号 */
{
    int i = 1, p = L.r[0].next;
    while (p)
    {
        adr[i++];
        p = L.r[p].next;
    }
}//Sort

void ReArrange(SLinkListType &L, int adr[])
/* adr给出静态链表L的有序次序，即L.r[adr[i]]是第i小的记录。 */
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < L.length; i++)
    {
        if (adr[i] != i)
        {
            j = i;
            L.r[0] = L.r[i];
            while (adr[j] != i)
            /* 调整(*L).r[adr[j]]的记录到位直到adr[j]=i为止 */
            {
                k = adr[j];
                printf("%d", k);
                /* 如：adr[1] = 6，则 K = 6，将 r[6] 赋值到 r[1], 同时同步adr[], 然后将 adr[1] 移动 adr[6]*/

                L.r[j] = L.r[k];        /* L.r[j] = L.r[adr[j]] */
                adr[j] = j;
                j = k;                  /* 记录按序到位 */
            }
            L.r[j] = L.r[0];            /* L.r[6] = L.r[0] */
            adr[j] = j;                 /* 同步 adr[] */
        }
    }
}//ReArrange

void Print(SLinkListType L)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= L.length; i++)
    {
        printf("key=%d ord=%d next=%d\n", L.r[i].rc.key, L.r[i].rc.otherinfo, L.r[i].next);
    }
}//Print

#define N 8

    void main()
    {
        RedType d[N] = { {49,1},{38,2},{65,3},{97,4},{76,5},{13,6},{27,7},{49,8} };
        SLinkListType a, b;
        int *adr = NULL, i = 0;         /* 内存分配有误，adr 的值超出范围  */
        TableInsert(a, d, N);
        b = a;          /* 复制静态链表l2与l1相同 */
        printf("排序前:\n");
        Print(a);
        Arrange(a);
        printf("a排序后:\n");
        Print(a);
        adr = (int *)malloc((b.length + 1) * sizeof(int));
        Sort(b, adr);
        for (i = 1; i <= b.length; ++i)
        {
            printf("adr[%d] = %d", i, adr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        ReArrange(b, adr);
        printf("b排序后:\n");
        Print(b);
    }
```

why when i defined int *adr = NULL i already let it equal NULL, but the  value of adr out of the limit, and get an error: the Read rights conflict, how to  define a pointer variable, so that the system don`t distribution a unknown pointer value. if define a NULL pointer, what is the pointer value , is my initialization was wrong? how to initialization a pointer

Comment: How does jumping into uncommented code feels like: [cave-jump](https://oddviser.com/photo/idea/1600/1562.jpg?1505480291), since you like images. Seriously now though, don't post images, copy paste text instead.

Comment: `void main` is not properly formed C++

Comment: is your question why `adr` has an invalid value when debugging? In your screenshot the assignment to `NULL` has not yet executed so `adr` is an uninitialised value, if you step to the next line it will be null.

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes: Don't use `NULL` or `malloc` in C++. If you need to use pointer then use `new[]` to allocate. And you don't really need to use pointers and your own explicit dynamic allocation at all here, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you're stepping through the code in a debugger, and stopped at the line

```
int *adr = NULL, i = 0;
```

and wonder why `adr` is not a null pointer?

Then that's because the initialization haven't happened yet. If you take one more step then the initialization will happen and `adr` should become `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of " int    `*adr = NULL;`   , try to use 
int *adr
`adr = new int;`
If you use  `int *adr = NULL` , it will cause to create an insufficient memory . 
`adr = new int;` - creates new dynamic memory. NULL is used to after deleting pointer !!!